# objective-c printing during the loop

Tags: objective-c, loops

how can I print during the loop?

I have an array who call a method

```
for (NSDictionary *item in allItems) {
    [self printa:item];
};
```

In that method I have NSLog and is printed dooring the loop, but waiting the end of the loop before print every elements, every images.

I tryed with blocks but for some reasons doesn't work.

I am looking for asyncronous, how can I do?

EDIT - Add more code:

This is the code in printa:

Start method:

```
-(void)printa:(NSDictionary*)item
```

Part of code:

```
bubble = [NSBubbleData dataWithText:testo date:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0] type:BubbleTypeSomeoneElse];
bubble.avatar = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];
[bubbleData addObject:bubble];
[bubbleTable reloadData];
NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:bubbleData.count inSection:0];
[bubbleTable scrollToRowAtIndexPath:path atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];
```

testo and imgData data are from server and are inside the NSDictionary

```
NSString *testo=[item objectForKey:@"messaggio"];
```

thanks in advance

Comment: the loop is locked until the end

Comment: What happens in printa ?

Comment: I added more code, just the interested part

Comment: I don't see an NSLog() statement ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking why your `NSLog` statements print during the loop's execution, but elements and images don't render until after the loop is completed then your problem is probably due to your loop not executing on the main thread. You said you tried blocks, but unless you put that block on the main queue it isn't going to help. I'd need to see the code within `printa` to know for sure.

Comment: Thanks i add more code, I hope you can help me. Thanks